# int(6) Returns the beginning of the content in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My Laravel application was working fine but suddenly happened something that I didn't know
on any request that I sent by GET method, there is an extra `int(6)` at the beginning of the response 
and in JSON it responding `int(6)[{'a'=>'a'}]`
the instruction is written in api.php

Could you help me, please!

Comment: Maybe a leftover "debug" `echo` somewhere?

Comment: Seems that there is a `var_dump` call present somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like output from `var_dump()`, so look for it in your code and if nothing us found, also check `vendor/` to ensure none of your dependency is polluted.